# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value to data type int

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

What am I doing wrong here?

```
string favorites = "210,213";

sqlCommand.CommandText = "select * from clients (nolock) 
    where Deleted = 0 and ClientID in (@favorites)";
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@favorites", favorites);
```

One other note: the "210,213" is just an example.  It could be any length of numbers.  That is why I am using the SQL IN operator.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't you not need `int.Parse` ?

Comment: what is the datatype of ClientID?

Comment: Please use the tags to categorize your question. Please don't use things like "C# ADO.NET" in your titles.

Comment: int.Parse will not work on a comma separated string.  ClientID is an int. (Sorry about the title).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how parameters work. You are actually trying to get clients where ClientID is **equal to** '210,213'. Well, that's not a number, so there's a failure.

Parametrized queries and `IN` clause are actually not trivially implemented together if your `IN` list size is dynamic, changing from time to time.

Read this SO question and answers: [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause)

Generally, you'd have to dynamically assemble your SQL query, always keeping in mind issues like [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Further reading:

- [Best practice between these two queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031693/best-practice-between-these-two-queries/7031810#7031810)
- [Deleting from sqlite database using IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442205/deleting-from-sqlite-database-using-in/6442392#6442392)
- [problem using Oracle parameters in SELECT IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155146/problem-using-oracle-parameters-in-select-in/6155215#6155215)
- [Is it possible to use query parameters to fill the IN keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589931/is-it-possible-to-use-query-parameters-to-fill-the-in-keyword)

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite certain you are going to need to generate the commandtext with the favorites string. There is no built in sql type for an array. You can probably protect yourself against a sql attack by making sure you generate the favorites from a list of integers.

Comment: It's not an array.  I am using the SQL IN operator.

Comment: understood-- but I think behind the scenes your parameter must match up to a type in sql server. Your asking SQL server to treat your parameter as an array, but sql server doesn't have a built in array. Let's say you were writing your command in T-SQL how would it translate? What would the datatype of @favorites be? A string? Try it-- it won't work. I've run into this before in T-SQL and I'm quite certain your issue is the same from the .net side. I think the answer above says this as well.